# $L^r_M = i_* \circ \hat{L}^{r-1}_M \circ i^*$ by the projection formula and the Poincare duality

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, derived-categories, sheaf-cohomology

This is a question arising when I am reading

> M. A. A. de Cataldo, L. Migliorini - *The Hard Lefschetz Theorem and the topology of semismall maps,* Ann. sci. École Norm. Sup., Serie 4 35 (2002) 759-772.

I give a reduction of the semantics. Let $M$ be a line bundle (in fact it is a lef line bundle), $Y$ is the zero locus of a non zero section of $M$. Assume the Chern class of $M_{\vert Y}$ satisfies the condition of the Hard Lefschetz. What we want to prove is that
$$L^r_M = i_* \circ \hat{L}^{r-1}_M \circ i^*,$$
where $L$ means wedge product with a Chern class and $\hat{L}_M = L_{M_{\vert Y}}$.

I could give a proof my self. Let $Y = \{f_1 = 0\}$ and $f_2$ is another section of $M$ traversing $Y$. Note that $c_M = [\sqrt{-1}\partial \bar{\partial} f_1 ] = [\sqrt{-1}\partial \bar{\partial} f_2 ]$ and $c_{M_{\vert Y}} = [\sqrt{-1}\partial \bar{\partial} f_2\circ i ]= i^*[\sqrt{-1}\partial \bar{\partial} f_2 ] = i*c_M$. So
$$i_* \circ \hat{L}^{r-1}_M \circ i^* \omega = i_* i^*({c_M^{r-1} \wedge \omega}).$$
It remains to show that $i_*i^* = L_M$. This can be seen by $<i_*i^* \alpha , \beta >_X = <i^* \alpha , i^* \beta>_Y = <i^* (\alpha \wedge \bar{ \beta}) , 1>_Y = <\alpha \wedge \bar{ \beta}, c_M>_X = <\alpha, \beta \wedge c_M>_X =<\alpha \wedge c_M, \beta>_X$. So $i_*i^* = L_M$.

However, in the article it is said that this is proved by the projection formula and the Poincaré duality. I don't understand how it works and some explanation could help a lot, not only on this question but also the understanding of the cohomology theory. It's more appreciated if you can work on derived categories.

Comment: "wedge product with a Chern class": you mean with  $h:=c_1(M)$. Then $\hat{L}_M$ is the product with $i^*h$; for $x$ a cohomology class:  $i_*\bigl((i^*h)^{r-1}\cdot i^*x\bigr)= i_*1\cdot h^{r-1}\cdot x$ (projection formula) $=h^r\cdot x$.

Comment: I thought that the projection formula is the sheaf version here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_formula. And I don't know how to relate sheaves with the classes of zero locus of their sections.

Comment: The term "projection formula" is also (and originally, I think) used for cohomology or Chow ring.

Comment: @abx That could make sense!